# How to read CSV file and save data in database nodejs and comsmosdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions

how to convert CSV file into JSON format and save data in Cosmos DB using node js.

Comment: Please share what have you tried.

Comment: you can use any npm package to convert csv to json like https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use this npm
npm install csvtojson

```
const csvPath ='<csv file path>'
const csvToJson =require('csvtojson')
csvToJson()
.fromFile(csvPath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);

})
```